# Calling the functions which are already in the callstack

Tags: python, callstack

I wanted to do something like the following. It is an Euclid's algorithm.
1. Why is it not working when I wanted to call the function which is already in the call stack?
2. How can I make it work?

```
import sys
def __block_1__():
        __block_2__()
def __block_2__():
        global b,a
        b,a=None,None
        __block_3__()
 def __block_3__():
        global b,a
        a=int(raw_input())
        __block_4__()
 def __block_4__():
        global b,a
        b=int(raw_input())
        __block_5__()
 def __block_5__():
        global b,a
        if a==b:
                __block_6__()
        else:
                __block_7__()
 def __block_6__():
        global b,a
        __block_8__()
 def __block_8__():
        global b,a
        sys.exit(0)
 def __block_7__():
        global b,a
        if a<b:
                __block_9__()
        else:
                __block_10__()
 def __block_9__():
        global b,a
        b=b-a
        __block_5__
 def __block_10__():
        global b,a
        a=a-b
        __block_5__
__block_1__()
```

Comment: In your blocks 9 and 10 you aren't calling `__block_5__` because you forgot the parentheses.  Also your code is difficult to read.  Why are you putting all those underscores all over the place?

Comment: it was an auto generated code. Sorry I didn't notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That has to be the craziest implementation of Euclid's GCD algorithm I've ever seen! :) And since it uses recursion *and* subtraction, it's not very efficient. OTOH, I guess it's intriguing, especially since it was auto-generated. (How was it auto-generated, BTW?)

I normally use:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if a < b:
        a, b = b, a
    while b > 0:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
```

In Python, we try to avoid using globals, but I guess we can forgive your auto-generator for that sin. Note that you only need the `global` statement when you want to *modify* a global variable, it's not required merely to read a global.

Apart from the missing parentheses in the call to **block_5** that BrenBarn mentioned, your program doesn't have any kind of output statement, so once it calculates the gcd it doesn't actually do anything with it. :)

Also note that if either of the args are <= 0 then the recursion stack blows up.

Anyway, I decided to clean your code up & get rid of the redundant blocks, on the off-chance that others might like to trace through the algorithm to see why it works.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Calculate the gcd of two positive integers

    Uses a recursive state machine implemetation of the naive form 
    of Euclid's algorithm.

    From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928184/calling-the-functions-which-are-already-in-the-callstack

    Modified by PM 2Ring 2014.09.19
'''

def block3():
    global a
    a = int(raw_input('a: '))
    block4()

def block4():
    global b
    b = int(raw_input('b: '))
    block5()

def block5():
    if a == b:
        block8()
    else:
        block7()

def block7():
    if a < b:
        block9()
    else:
        block10()

def block8():
    print a
    exit()

def block9():
    global b
    b -= a
    block5()

def block10():
    global a
    a -= b
    block5()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    block3()
```

I think you'll agree that my version's a bit more readable. :)

Comment: I have been developing an educational software to draw a programming flowchart and execute it to see the result. In the software, each block represents one function. So it is generated this way. You can see my program here. https://github.com/ggtulga/blockTest

Comment: any suggestions and advices are welcome.